# Фоновое выполнение функции в PHP

Tags: php

Есть функция, которая парсит excel и добавляет обработанную информацию в БД. Сейчас функция обрабатывает данные, выводит тут же и лог в html прям на странице загрузки файла. Задача: выполнять функцию фоном. Как выполнить функцию фоном? Чтобы пользователь нажав кнопку "выполнить" и перезагрузив страницу или перейдя куда либо функция продолжала работать и обрабатывать данные, писать лог в БД и выполнять прочие условия. 

P.S. использую wordpress - может как то кому то поможет

Answer (score 1):

1. Создаете рядом скрипт, например parse.php, выполняющий необходимую операцию.
2. Делаете к нему асинхронный GET(ну или POST) запрос

Про то, как делать асинхронный запрос из PHP довольно много информации. Например в англоязычном стеке неоднократно разбирался этот вопрос.
Копипаста отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124462/asynchronous-php-calls

```
function post_without_wait($url, $params)
{
    foreach ($params as $key => &$val) {
      if (is_array($val)) $val = implode(',', $val);
        $post_params[] = $key.'='.urlencode($val);
    }
    $post_string = implode('&', $post_params);

    $parts=parse_url($url);

    $fp = fsockopen($parts['host'],
        isset($parts['port'])?$parts['port']:80,
        $errno, $errstr, 30);

    $out = "POST ".$parts['path']." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out.= "Host: ".$parts['host']."\r\n";
    $out.= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $out.= "Content-Length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n";
    $out.= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    if (isset($post_string)) $out.= $post_string;

    fwrite($fp, $out);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: забавно, то что в том англопосте многие люди написали что это не асинхронный код :)

Comment: и потом не проще было написать, что нужно сделать ajax запрос?

Comment: @MaximPro зачем ajax закрыл вкладку и сервер например `nginx` убил php скрипт

Comment: @MaximPro Тут есть нюанс. Код действительно не асинхронный, но запущенный им процесс будет выполняться в другом потоке, то есть как бы асинхронно. Де юро не асинхронный, де факто - практически асинхронный. :)

Answer (score 0):

Рецепт прост:

1. берём планировщик задач (cron)
2. делаем скрипт (queue.php)
3. и табличку в базе с очередью (queue)

И так настраиваем cron на выполнения скрипта каждую минуту. При загрузке страницы или выполнения действия, пишем `url` страницы для парсинга, к примеру. И так крон запускает скрипт парсинга который получает данные из таблички и запускает парсинг...

Answer (score 0):

В Wordpress для этого есть функция wp_schedule_single_event()